# PyMongo- Update an element in an array

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am using python 3.6 and MongoDB 3.6.3. [This is my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVdkq.png)
And this is my code:

```
def update_device_last_activity(last_activity, peername, interface):
filter_param = {
    'peername': {
        'ip': peername[0],
        'port': peername[1],
        'devices.interface': interface
    }
}
set_param = {
    '$set': {
        'devices.$.last_activity': last_activity
    }
}
db.modules.update(filter_param, set_param)
```

[This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa0fj.png)
Nothing changes in the db! What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Try `filter_param = {     'peername': {         'ip': peername[0],         'port': peername[1] },      'devices.interface': interface     }`

Comment: omg can't belive I didn't see that. 10x!